# IEDriverserver.exe crashes sometimes using selenium. Looks it's related to memory, how can I increase it?

Tags: selenium, crash, selenium-iedriver, iedriverserver

I hava a maven project which runs selenium tests using IEDriver.exe. Sometimes IEDriver crashes with the message "The instruction at 0x6b5bebe4 referenced memory at 0x6aaa6830". Looks like it's related to memory, should I increase the the memory when running the mvn test? If so, what command should I use?

The commands I use to run my selenium tests are: mvn test -Pmyprofile

```
    cucumber.runtime.CucumberException: 
org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: Unable to find element with id == USERID (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information) Command duration or timeout: 60.23 seconds. For documentation on this error, please visit:  http://seleniumhq.org/exceptions/no_such_element.html
Build info: version: '2.47.1', revision: 'unknown', time: '2015-07-30 11:02:44'
System info: host: '10-118-144-236', ip: '10.118.144.236', os.name: 'Windows Server 2012 R2', os.arch: 'x86', os.version: '6.3', java.version: '1.8.0_25'
Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.ie.InternetExplorerDriver
Capabilities [{browserAttachTimeout=0, enablePersistentHover=true, ie.forceCreateProcessApi=false, ie.usePerProcessProxy=false, ignoreZoomSetting=false, handlesAlerts=true, version=11, platform=WINDOWS, nativeEvents=true, ie.ensureCleanSession=false, elementScrollBehavior=0, ie.browserCommandLineSwitches=, requireWindowFocus=false, browserName=internet explorer, initialBrowserUrl=http://localhost:30820/, takesScreenshot=true, javascriptEnabled=true, ignoreProtectedModeSettings=true, enableElementCacheCleanup=true, cssSelectorsEnabled=true, unexpectedAlertBehaviour=dismiss}]
Session ID: c861d008-b25b-4845-80ae-4c99ffb5a970
*** Element info: {Using=id, value=USERID}
    at com.cucumber.StepDefinitions.DNIOrderSearch.feature(DNIOrderSearch.java:44)
Caused by: org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: 
Unable to find element with id == USERID (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)
Command duration or timeout: 60.23 seconds
```

Comment: Can you update the question with complete error stack trace?

Comment: just added the error stack trace.